# Fitting a mixture of gaussians with negative weights

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian

I know Gaussian Mixture Models are used for distribution of points and thus the functions they represent are positive (PDFs are postivie). However I want to approximate a function using GMMs which could also be negative. Is there any way to approximate negative values using GMMs? 
here is an example:

[image: a function and its approximation with GMM]

as it's obvious in the plot, using a mixture of two Gaussians it's much better to cover have one positive and one negative Gaussian as opposed to what matlab `fit` function finds. Is there any way in MATLAB to accomplish this?

Comment: @Suever I don't think it's mathematically the same ... for example in the picture attached maybe after taking the `abs` it will fit them with a single Gaussian.

Comment: Have you considered applying standard fitting techniques to both the negative and positive part of the signal separately?

Comment: @mikkola but then again that might complicate things, say if I want four Gaussian approximation how many positive and how many negative should I consider? one way is to run every combination and choose the combination that gives the best fit. But I thought there might be a more convenient strategy.